# Excel 2007 Custom Data Validation, Excluding characters in large range

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, data-validation

Trying to create data validation (absolutely no macros, it is simply not an option), where a user can type in only Basic characters 
(A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,~,',\,/)
So what I tried to do is create a validation that checked for certain characters and popped an error message if they found them So my data validation formula is the following.

=ISERROR(FIND("&",D17:D110))

Where D17:D110 is the range of cells that will all be validated.
So after a user is typing in his values, if the cell he is currently editing, contains a "&" it will throw an error. This method works beautifully.
However!
I need to disallow more than that one character, so I tried.

=ISERROR((OR(FIND("&",D17:D110),FIND("^",D17:D110))))

Not only does this then NOT work for "^" it also breaks finding "&".

So what I need is a way to either

1. Block multiple characters from being allowed
2. Only allow the above listed characters.

Caveat:
Because of how the formula is being added (.NET OfficeOpenXml) I can't reference JUST the one cell by itself like you could if you entered it in Excel and drug the formula. It's a limitation of the API. That's the reason I found a way to do use with the entire range.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it generates an error inside the OR, making OR failing to evaluate. Also, you should use AND.

Try this:

> =AND(ISERROR(FIND("&",A1)),ISERROR(FIND("^",A1)))

Using AND, because ISERROR will be TRUE if the char is NOT FOUND.

> and(notA,notB) = not(or(A,B))

so if A=true means & is found, and B=true means ^ is found, I believe you can see the logic

Comment: Ha! Yes that makes so much sense. Excel formulas have no real error correction. That works beautifully! Thanks.